# How can I find the equation of the shape formed by the intersection of two ellipses?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find the equation of shape formed by the intersection of two ellipses. I have foci of each ellipse. The pictorial representation of the problem is shown in the figure below.

[Clicke to see figure: Ellipse intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X8xA.png)

How can I generate the equation of shape shown pink colour?

I don't have that much base in mathematics, so if my question has any problem, please provide me feedback.

Thanks in advance

Manu

Comment: You will have to intersect the two ellipses. This is hardly a trivial matter, but a search on MSE should bring up a good number of methods.

Comment: You should tell us more precisely what you intend to do because there are several ways to describe this shape.

Comment: By the way, it is not enough to know the foci.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: with the given geometry, finding the two intersection points is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pink area can be described by a system of inequations, for instance

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{(x-x_1)^2}{a_1^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b_1^2}\le 1,\\
\dfrac{(x-x_2)^2}{a_2^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b_2^2}\le 1.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Daoust : Thanks for your reply

Comment: Is there any single equation with multiple parameters to describe this shape(I saw an equation of hyperellipse with 3 foci) ?

Comment: @ManuFrancis: if you don't tell me the purpose, I can't answer.

Comment: I need to find the projection of a cylinderical hole in 2D plane by using a point source illumination at different positions. The projection of hole will be an intersection of two ellipses. This is my purpose

Comment: @ManuFrancis: I see. But what kind of representation do you need ? What kind of processing follows ? (Computing the area, filling in a raster image, flattening as a polygon… ?)